# Oracle ADF stop validation on empty table row, validate in popup form instead

Tags: java, oracle, validation, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm currently developing a simple application which does crud operations on a few tables.

It looks like this:

[image]

I have a problem with the add item form, invoked by pressing the button saying "Nova jedinica mjere". It opens a popup containing an ADF form as follows:

[image]

As you can see it does a create insert operation on popup fetch event, creating an empty row. When I fill the form with data, and press OK(the ok button is handled in the bean, doing a commit operation), I get an empty error message as follows:

[image]

This only happens if the table is editable(consisting of input text elements). If it is set to click to edit, this problem does not occur. How can I make validation only occur on form fields?

If you need any more info, please let me know because I too am new to adf.

EDIT:

This is the page in question:(posted as a pastebin link to not take up much space).

http://pastebin.com/5TKyPxEs

The form in the popup is a static region from a task flow with a method call and a page:

http://pastebin.com/9h69fRW4

Comment: Provide some jsf code please, most probably you need to put both your popup form and table in subform component

Comment: Well, in my opinion its plain wrong to use both form and table row editing in the same time. However try to surround your table and region with `subform` component.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say that when you enter the value in the form and Click OK, it should be there in the Table,If so, the values are not getting displayed in Table. It means your Iterator is not fetching the values. You have to Refresh your Iterator, VO and Table Compoent through Bean. So that the values in the form once you click OK, it will be there in the Table.